# Локализация сайта

Tags: asp.net, c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Пишу CMS на ASP.NET MVC, нужно, чтобы CMS умел работать со многими языками и можно было изменять тексты без перекомпиляции приложения.

Сейчас я храню данные для локализаций в БД. При старте приложения данные берутся из БД и кладутся в кэш (на случай, если необходимо будет получить данные не в браузере), после чего генерируется js файл с названием типа `locale_ruRU.js` и данными в формате

```
var localeData = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2', // ...
}
```

В View'ах я использую хелпер:

```
<div>@Html.Localize("key")</div>
```

Который генерирует **span** с необходимыми аттрибутами. `<span class="localized" data-locale-key="key"></span>`

После чего javascript обрабатывает эти тэги примерно так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.localized').each(function() {
        $(this).html(localeData[$(this).attr('data-locale-key')]);
    });
});
```

Локализацию через javascript делаю, дабы не обращаться слишком много к кэшу (помимо внутреннего кэша поддерживается еще memcached и redis).

Правильно ли я делаю? Может есть способы проще и быстрее? И как локализировать большие тексты?

Comment: Я так понял, что при загрузке каждой страницы (даже самой маленькой) у Вас будет грузиться locale_ruRU.js с локализацией всего сайта?

Comment: @V_V_Shinkevich, да, но там файл не большой (на данный момент всего 15кб), к тому же, он попадает в кэш

Answer (score 1):

Три года назад была статья на  [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/company/knoema/blog/149802/) с чем-то подобным и приводилась ссылка на библиотеку. Посмотрите, может, поможет...